# MySQL: Selecting random things starting with a X letter

Tags: mysql, database, random, words

I am using this database:
http://www.4redpixels.com/uploads/words.sql

I want to select a **random** word starting with a X (unknown) letter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the best way to get words that start with a particular letter is to use `like`:

```
select w.word
from words w
where w.word like 'x%'
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `words(word)`.  In addition, if the list is really long, there are better ways to get a random row than just `order by rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT `word`
FROM `words`
WHERE STRCMP(SUBSTRING(`word`,1,1),'x') = 0
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0,1
```